# Representing time ( microsecs or millisecs ) as a float

Tags: rest

We have developed a RestFul API where the request body takes in "latency" in millisecs which is an integer (Ex: 50 ms ).

Now we have to support "latency" in microsecs in the new release. Ideally if "latency" was defined as float earlier, we could have used the same field with a floating value for microsecs. We are now stuck and have to define another integer "latencyU" which would be in microsecs.

What would be the best approach in REST so that even if we change the granularity in future, we would not have to change the server code.

Answer (score 0):

Leave `latency` as is. Add `latency_units` which must be ether `"milliseconds"` or `"microseconds"`. It defaults to `"milliseconds"` if nothing is specified, maintaining backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion